# Need SQL Query for the following data and Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table with Emp_salary name.

**Table data**

```
id  name    Slry
1   Ram     1500
2   janak   500
3   Anuj    400
4   Hardik  2000
5   Amit    2500
6   Atul    3000
7   Rahul   3500
8   Jay     4000
9   Parth   1500
10  Lalit   600
11  Ramesh  5000
```

**My Que is** : I will pass name of Emp in where condition.
And I want O/P like all Emp will come out that’s Salary will Less than that Emp’s salary(That I was pass in where condition)

*Ex.*

If i pass **Lalit**                 if i pass **Atul**
O/P will be like                O/P will be like

```
name    Slry                    name    Slry
janak   500                     janak   500
Anuj    400                     Anuj    400
Lalit   600                     Lalit   600
                                Ram     1500
                                Hardik  2000
                                Amit    2500
                                Atul    3000
                                Parth   1500
```

**Don’t use “Sub Query”  or “Function” 
I need only Simple SQL Query for that.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-equality join:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1 , 'Ram   ', 1500),
    (2 , 'janak ', 500 ),
    (3 , 'Anuj  ', 400 ),
    (4 , 'Hardik', 2000),
    (5 , 'Amit  ', 2500),
    (6 , 'Atul  ', 3000),
    (7 , 'Rahul ', 3500),
    (8 , 'Jay   ', 4000),
    (9 , 'Parth ', 1500),
    (10, 'Lalit ', 600 ),
    (11, 'Ramesh', 5000)
)T(id,  name,    Slry)
)
SELECT S1.name, S1.Slry
FROM Src S1
JOIN Src S2 ON S1.Slry<=S2.Slry
WHERE S2.name='Lalit'
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use a CTE to determine reference salary and then get only employees having a smaller salary than this salary by using a non-equality join.

```
DECLARE @empName as NVARCHAR(100) = 'Atul';

WITH cteRefEmp
AS
(
    SELECT slry
    FROM tmp.Emp
    WHERE name = @empName
)
SELECT E.name, E.slry
FROM
    tmp.Emp E
    INNER JOIN cteRefEmp RE ON E.slry <= RE.slry
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in this way also :

```
SELECT emp.name , emp.slry 

from emp

WHERE  emp.slry  <= (SELECT slry FROM emp WHERE emp.name = 'Lalit')
```